# Integer to Roman while loop explanation-Python

Tags: python, loops, data-conversion, roman-numerals

I am trying to understand the `while` loop and `sorted` call in the program to convert a number to Roman numerals below.

```
numerals = { 1 : "I", 4 : "IV", 5 : "V", 9 : "IX", 10 : "X", 40 : "XL",
             50 : "L", 90 : "XC", 100 : "C", 400 : "CD", 500 : "D", 900 : "CM", 1000 : "M" }

num = 58  # LVIII

roman = ''

for k, v in sorted(numerals.items(), reverse=True):
    while num >= k:
        roman += v
        num -= k

print(roman)
```

Questions:
1) Why doesn't the code work if `numerals.items()` is used instead of `sorted(numerals.items(), reverse=True)`? (For example, 58 would result in `IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII` instead of `LVIII`.) When using a breakpoint on that line it looks like the order remains same both with and without `sorted`.

2) The first Roman numeral is `L`. Why? When debugging I noticed it starts counting down from 1000. When it reaches 50, I see that `roman == 'L'`. The code tests if `num >= k`. 1000 (M) is also greater than 58. Why does the condition `num >= k` result in `L` being the first digit?

Comment: `the code does not work unless "sorted(numerals.items(), reverse=True)" is used` What does it do without it? Where do you put it? Also, AFAICT, `num=58 answer> LVIII` is invalid syntax. Was `answer> LVIII` supposed to be a comment (beginning with `#`)?

Comment: LVIII is just for reference in case anyone is running the code. Without using sorted  it prints IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII. To get LVIII need to use for k,v in sorted(numerals.items(), reverse=True):

Comment: Have you sat down and worked out what the code does step by step? Use pencil and paper or gratuitous `print`s if necessary. You need to develop the ability to do so if you're going to write code. Others answering this question for you are doing you no favors. If you already understand *what* the code does, then you need to be more specific about what particular behavior confuses or surprises you. Most likely, the answer to why the language behaves those specific ways is already available somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `sorted(numerals.items(), reverse=True)` not only means sorted, but also means sorted in reverse. The key point is `reverse=True`. Because we must compare to the largest Roman first. From `M` to `I`, not from `I` to `M`.
2. `"The logic says num>=k. 1000,M is also greater than num 58."` I think you have misunderstanding here. for `while num>=k:` it find less or equal than num, not large, so `L` will be the first one.

Hope that will help you.

Comment: Great. It is clear now. The problem of not sorting and starting the comparison from largest to smallest is it will pick the IIII values as match. Thank You.

Comment: `dict.items()` is not guaranteed to have any order. Your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @jpmc26, sorry about that, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Without `sorted`, the loop would begin with `1, 'I'`. It would then be used as many times as possible. In this case, this would result in 58 `I`s. (It would then continue onto `4, 'IV'`, `5, 'V'`, etc., but `num` would be 0.) With `sorted`, the loop begins with `1000, 'M'`, then `900, 'CM'`, etc. (The reason the sorting was not visible in the debugger is that [`sorted` returns a **new** list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).) When it reaches `50, 'L'`, the while loop tests if `58 >= 50` (you got the order wrong in your observation), which is true. It then sets `num` to 8 and `roman` to `'L'`. It then continues to loop to get the remaining digits.

Answer (score -1):

Python3:

```
# num=58# answer> LVIII

num = 58
numerals = { 1 : "I", 4 : "IV", 5 : "V", 9 : "IX", 10 : "X", 40 : "XL",
        50 : "L", 90 : "XC", 100 : "C", 400 : "CD", 500 : "D", 900 : "CM", 1000 : "M" }
roman=''
#reserve numerals
for k, v in sorted(numerals.items(), reverse=True):
    while num>=k:
        roman=roman+v
        num = num - k
print(roman)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I updated the example code, that is working. I think this is same as @recnac

Comment: That is not what was asked. I think they did have working code.

Comment: The question is updated to `for k, v in sorted(numerals.items(), reverse=True):`. Of course, now, the question 's code is no problem.